# How to Append Arrray List Data Into Text File

Tags: c#, arraylist

Below is the code.

I want to add the Array List Data into Text File.At this time it Inserts the data but when i add new data it overwrites the previous data and just add new one so i want that it will ask that you want that the data already exists you want to overwrite or append if data do not exist it simply append to the file.

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\Precision\Desktop\testing\data.txt"))
{
    foreach (var obj in dirList)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Record Saved Successfully...");
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: You need to check the existence of file and content, based on that you need to write your logic as per problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

call this function from foreach i.e. foreach (var obj in dirList){this.WriteToFile(obj.ToString());}

public void WriteToFile(string text)
        {

```
        string path = path\fileName.txt";
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(text);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
        string outFile = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
        bool isAppend = true;

        ArrayList dirList = new ArrayList();
        dirList.Add("foo");
        dirList.Add("bar");
        dirList.Add("baz");

        if(File.Exists(outFile))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Output file already exists...");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'x' to overwrite or any other to append.");
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
            isAppend = (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.X);
        }

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile, isAppend))
        {
            foreach (var obj in dirList)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(obj);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Idon't want to overwrite the file i want to overwrite data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `File.CreateText` to `File.AppendText`